# Vim: searching upward/downward in file from specific point/position

Tags: vim, search, administration

I want to search a word from my current cursor position in vim to upward in file.

How to achieve this?

Also how to do same for downward in file.

Comment: The `:set hlsearch` and `:set incsearch` commands might be of interest to you.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

To search in reverse from your cursor for a word, just use `?`. So to find the word "fred" you would issue `?fred`.

For forward searching you use `/`, using "fred" as an example again you would issue `/fred`.

If you want to continue searching for the same term, in the same direction you can use the `n` command. (Or you can issue `?` or `/` without arguments).

Comment: Since OP searches for a word from its current cursor position which I understand as word below cursor, he can also use the star * operator to search downward.
There is also an equivalent for going upward but I do not rember it and it is exactly what I am looking for.

Comment: `*` (forward) and `#` (backwards) search for the word under the cursor. No need to type the word with `?`

Answer (score 18):

Typing `?search text` in command mode searches backward from point while `/search text` searches forward.

Typing `n` goes to the next instance of the search text in the direction you were last searching and typing `N` looks in the opposite direction of your last search.

Comment: `Shift+N` so intuitive. Why bother with `?` at all?